# Cannot get Selenium to locate an element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium to automatically click the next_frame button but I do not know why the element can not be stored into the next_frame variable.How do I get the next_frame variable to locate the element?

```
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())

driver.implicitly_wait(15)


activity_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "activity-title")))
if activity_name.text == 'Instruction' or activity_name.text == 'Warm-Up' or activity_name.text == 'Summary':
    activity_status = driver.find_element_by_id('activity-status')

    while activity_status.text != "Complete":

        next_frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bottom-area"]/div[3]/ol/li[5]/a')

        next_frame.click()

        activity_status = driver.find_element_by_id('activity-status')

    driver.find_element_by_class_name('nav-icon').click()

else:
    pass
```

Here is the message it showed me

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="bottom-area"]/div[3]/ol/li[5]/a"}
```

Comment: Is this all the relevant code? I don't see where you even open a URL

Comment: The most likely reason if the xpath is correct is that it is in an iframe or shadow root if you get nosuchelement.

Comment: I put the driver.get() in a function but I left it out to be more concise.

Comment: oh, I see. it is in an iframe.